# Javascript not executing after webpack watch

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I've got an AngularJS (1.6) app written using webpack 3.10.  I have an entry file (`Application.ts`) which creates the module, runs it, and then bootstraps it to the document.

This works fine on the first build, however once I save a change, let webpack watch do its work then refresh the browser, the application hasn't bootstrapped.  By putting in `console.log` near the top of my `Application.ts` file, it's clear that the entry file isn't being executed.

If I stop the webpack watch process and restart it and refresh the browser, the app bootstraps successfully.

What's strange is that this *was* working successfully in the past, then suddenly just stopped.  I put up with it for a while and it suddenly it started to work again!   Then last week it just broke itself again.

**Edit 1**

So I thought I'd compare the two generated bundles, the first being a bundle on the first run of `webpack`, and the second the updated bundle after a minute change to a ts file, created via webpack watch.

I'm surprised to see such a huge difference between the two files, given all I did was change `protected test: Function;` to be `protected test2: Function;`.  I'd expect the two bundles to be virtual identitcal, baring the change I'd just mentioned?

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 1000
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            /\.js$/,
            /\.d\.ts$/
        ]),
    ]
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const convertPathsToAliases = require("convert-tsconfig-paths-to-webpack-aliases").default;
const tsconfig = require("./tsconfig");
const aliases = convertPathsToAliases(tsconfig);

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, "src", "Application.ts"),
        vendor: [
            "angular", 
            "angular-route", 
            "angular-sanitize", 
            "angular-paging",
            "ng-redux", 
            "ng-file-upload", 
            "ng-redux-router",
            "ngmap", 
            "toastr",
            "angular-drag-and-drop-lists",
            "angular-ui-bootstrap",
            "redux-thunk", 
            "redux-logger", 
            "lodash"],

    },
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/[name].hotels.bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        alias: aliases
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: "jQuery"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: "tslint-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["vendor"]
        })
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2016",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["es2016" ,"dom"],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "Models": ["src/app/models/index"],
            "Utilities": ["src/app/utilities"],
            "App/*": ["src/app/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting my machine resolves the issue.

I know it's a really disappointing answer, however occasionally this "bug" randomly presents itself where `watch` will no longer build the bundles correctly.  A restart has fixed the issue each time.

Comment: wow. I didn't see that coming. Glad you got it working again!

Comment: I had a completely different problem with watch and the reboot also fixed it for me, weird.